# customizing order of Javascript Loading in drupal & adding a new JS to that list

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-themes

I want to customize the order of loading javascripts in drupal 7. I am using Bartik theme. If I want to add a new JS and load it somewhere in between those list. How can I achieve the same? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) function

The second parameter is $options, that you can pass the group of your Javascript file

- JS_LIBRARY: Any libraries, settings, or jQuery plugins.
- JS_DEFAULT: Any module-layer JavaScript.
- JS_THEME: Any theme-layer JavaScript.

Also you can pass the weight of your script to define the order you want.

Here is an example

```
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
  alert("Hello!"); });', 
  array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5)
);
```

I recommend you to read this article: [Managing javascript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722)

Answer (score 0):

If you want one javascript to get load before the other javascripts then, you can write hook_init() in module file and write drupal_add_js to inculde javascript you want to get load first.

and if the javascripts are external then you can directly use in html.tpl file in whatever order you want to load it.